# Invalid source fslightbox js I got this error on my website but on localhost works

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I got this error when I try to open my image with help of fslightbox and I got this error in the console

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'slice')
    at Object.getTypeFromResponseContentType (fslightbox.js:1:10541)
    at XMLHttpRequest.r
```

Can someone help to fix this problem what I did wrong, on localhost everything works well is it problem webp images?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doesn't support webp images has to change it to jpg or png